# How to pass parameters to react-highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

In a [documentation](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts) I see that I can pass config and I do it like:

```
render() {
        let config = this.config;

        return (
            <div className="column">
                <div className="ui segment">
                    <ReactHighcharts config = {config} options = {options}> </ReactHighcharts>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

But in standard highchart exists also `.theme()` method, in which we can pass additional parameters. How can I pass these parameters in the react-highcharts component?

Comment: It looks like you just pass in the theme through the `options` prop. For example, `title: {
        style: {
            color: '#666`
       }
}`

Comment: What you can try to do is accessing the ref object of ReactHighcharts. ReactHighcharts.chartRef should be the "real" highchart object, so maybe you can render ReactHighcharts with ref={ x => this.highchart = x } and then access it via this.highchart.chartRef.theme(...). But I want to mention that this is not an official way and extremely dangerous if you don't know what you do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation I see that `config` is a object that will be used to configure HighCharts. Have you tried to do something like:

```
const config = {
  theme: {
    zIndex: 6,
  },
}
```